# vuetify data-table + dragula

Tags: vuejs2, dragula, vuetify.js

I have a problem with making vuetify datatable work with dragula. I'm using the wrapper vue2-dragula.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrate the problem though i wasn't able to make dragular work per se

https://jsfiddle.net/Lscqm9je/

On my computer it's working as intended. The only problem is the datatable column alingment if you look on the first table, we loose the header / data alignment because i added a div in between template and tr

```
<v-data-table  v-bind:headers="headers" v-bind:items="items" hide-actions>
              <template slot="items" scope="props">
                <tbody v-dragula="tr" drake="first" class="container">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.round }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cat }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.p1 }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.p2 }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.statut }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
```

So i guess putting something in between table template and table row is a no-no. But it's the only way i found to make dragula directive work. The directive must be direct parent of the draggable element ( tr ). I also tried to put the directive within the template tag but it's doesn't seem to be possible.

```
<template slot="items" scope="props" v-dragula="tr" drake="first" class="container">
```

what i'm looking for is a table that look like the 2nd in the fiddle but with the dragula directive working. Someone have an idea ? 
I'm a beginner with no real programming degree so it might be something stupid, sorry in advance if it is :)

thank.

More information :

**this doesn't work :**

```
<template slot="items" scope="props" v-dragula="tr" drake="first" class="container">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.round }}</td>
```

**This work but the cell are dragged individually instead of the whole line.**

```
<template slot="items" scope="props">
                  <tr v-dragula="tr" drake="first" class="container">
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.round }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The console on the fiddle is giving a warning

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "tr" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. 
Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
(found in <Root>)
```

Looking at the vue-dragula readme page, `v-dragula="..."` should point to the data collection, not the element, so I assume it will be

```
<template slot="items" scope="props" v-dragula="items" drake="first" class="container">
```

This might get you a little further. At one point the second table was showing an icon upon dragging, but it's not doing so now, I'm not sure why. If I get any further clues, I'll update.

BTW, `<template>` instead of `<div>` is preferred, as `<table>` is touchy about internal tags (although might expect Vuetify to manage that issue).